# Unabe to make migrations to herokuapp: No module named 'django-heroku'

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, migrate

After finally deploying [my app to heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/rate-star-movies) I wanted to make migrations to my postgres database. I ran into a curious error:

```
(movie_app) ejan@linux-nr9m:~/github/Moviebase-web-app> heroku run python manage.p makemigrations
Running python manage.py makemigrations on ⬢ rate-star-movies... up, run.2515 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 15, in check_all_models
    models = apps.get_models()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 178, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 140, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 219, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/cp_django_barebones/settings.py", line 13, in <module>
    import django_heroku
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
```

What is remarkable about it is that even if I have installed django-heroku and it's also [in my requirements.txt](https://github.com/Medeon/Moviebase-web-app/blob/master/requirements.txt) and I have added the necessary lines in [my settings.py](https://github.com/Medeon/Moviebase-web-app/blob/master/cp_django_barebones/settings.py), it still gives me the error:

> No module named 'django_heroku'

I searched the internet (including stackoverflow) and the suggestions were to empty the requirements.txt file, deploy the app (which was supposed to uninstall all modules), then again deploy with the requirements.txt file restored to the old values. I simply could not deploy the app. Other suggestions were to install postgresql and psycopg2 first, which was not relevant because the packages were already installed.

I don't know what else to do, so does anyone have an idea about what could be causing the error or better how to solve it?

Comment: You've got both a requirements.txt and a Pipfile. It looks like Heroku is finding the Pipfile first and so ignores the requirements.txt. Remove one of them.

Comment: Thanks, I just deleted the pipfile and pipfile.lock, that solves the problem.